# Javascript prompt Message-Box not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have done all the codings, everything is working just fine. Only stuck in javascript. I can change color of the image-background. But, I cannot prompt a pop-up message when I click on an image, I have tried using "onclick". but still it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me suggestions or and example of a work. Please see my codings below--

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style> 
            th{ 
                width:60px; 
                height:60px; 
            } 
            table{ 
                border: 5px solid #FFBB78; 
                border-collapse:collapse; 
            } 
            td{ 
                width:60px; 
                height:60px; 
            } 
            tr{ 
                width:60px; 
                height:60px;  
            } 
            h1{ 
                color:#6633FF; 
            } 
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("king").style.backgroundColor="black";
 }
 function click(){
     /*var pawn = document.write.getElementById('pawn');
     var knight = document.write.getElementById('knight');
     var queen = document.write.getElementById('queen');
     var bishop = document.write.getElementById('bishop');
     var king = document.write.getElementById('king_1');
     var square = document.write.getElementById('sqaure');*/
     alert("This is a knight");
 }

 /*function promt_chess_piece(){
    //var knight = document.write.getElementById('knight');
    if (knight.value.lenght)
    {
        alert("This is the knight");
        knight.focus();
        return true;
    }
 }*/
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 

    $pictures = array( 
        //row 1
        "1,1" => '<img src="chess/br.gif" />',  
        "1,3" => '<img src="chess/bb.gif"/>', 
        "1,4" => '<img src="chess/bq.gif"/>',
        "1,5" => '<img src="chess/bk.gif"/>',
        "1,8" => '<img src="chess/br.gif"/>',
        //row 2
        "2,1" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,2" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,3" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,4" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,5" => '<img src="chess/bb.gif"/>', 
        "2,6" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,7" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>', 
        "2,8" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>',

        //row 3
        "3,3" => '<img src="chess/bn.gif"  onclick="click()"/>',
        "3,6" => '<img src="chess/bn.gif"/>',

        //row 4
        "4,5" => '<img src="chess/bp.gif"/>',

        //row 5
        "5,3" => '<img src="chess/wb.gif"/>',
        "5,5" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',

        //row 6 
        "6,4" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "6,6" => '<img src="chess/wn.gif"/>',

        //row 7
        "7,1" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,2" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,3" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,6" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,7" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',
        "7,8" => '<img src="chess/wp.gif"/>',

        //row 8
        "8,1" => '<img src="chess/wr.gif"/>',
        "8,2" => '<img src="chess/wn.gif"/>',
        "8,3" => '<img src="chess/wb.gif"/>',
        "8,4" => '<img src="chess/wq.gif"/>',
        "8,6" => '<img src="chess/wr.gif"/>',
        "8,7" => '<img src="chess/wk.gif" onmouseover="changeColor()" id="king" />',);//array ends here

    echo"<h1 align='center'>SAJID Chess Board</h1>"; 
    echo"<table border='1' align='center'>"; 

     for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++){      
          echo "<tr>"; 
          for($j = 1; $j <=8; $j++){ 
              if( ($i+$j)%2==0 ) { 
                echo"<td bgcolor='#99FF99'>"; 
              } 
              else { 
                echo"<td bgcolor='#9999CC'>"; 
                   } 


                if(isset($pictures["{$i},{$j}"]))//compares the pictures i and p 
                    echo $pictures["{$i},{$j}"]; 

                echo "</td>"; 
                } 
                echo "</tr>"; 
            } 


            echo "</table>"; 

        ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us the code so that we can help?

Comment: Looking at your code I don't see anything immediately wrong (there's a lot of code there). Look in the javascript console to see what your browser doesn't like about the page, if anything. also, look at the actual page source that this PHP produces. Do you see your img tag with the call to click written into the page as you expect? There's nothing obviously wrong with the call, as written.

Answer (score 0):

Are you definitely clicking on the image with the onclick attribute? Only one of images has this. That's the only thing I can see that could be the issue.